# Is possible to put a button on a row of a listview?

Tags: android, listview, button

I'm trying to put a button to delete a row of a listview. I've modified the layout of the single rows like this:

[image: Row]

With lst.setOnItemClickListener... I manage the click on the row, but I don't know how to click the button inside the list.

It can be done?

Comment: yes use custom adapter

Comment: 1st use Google, 2nd use Bing, 3rd search in Stackoverflow. This is answered many times.

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183107/in-listview-setonlistitem-not-working/27183190#27183190

Comment: Literally what listview was made for, to able to show any view combination in a list. In the adapter, you pass the activity as the onclicklistener to prevent a separate onclicklistener with an implicit reference from keeping your activity alive. Then do whatever like a regular method.

Answer (score 0):

Search on google "custom adapter"

Then the 5 first links :

[Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-custom-adapter-with-imageview.html

http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/listview-with-custom-adapter.html

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/adapters/create_a_custom_adapter_for_contacts/

Comment: I have a custom adapter yet, but I don't know how to differentiate between the click of the row, or the click of the button inside the row.

Comment: Implement click listener for both row and button.

Comment: Trying it... Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

Override your adapter getview method to handle the button click.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vehicals_details_row, parent,
            false);
    Button deleteImageView = (Button)  row.findViewById(R.id.DeleteImageView);
    deleteImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        });
    }
}
```

In your listItem xml layout, set the button to have the following attribute and it will cause the list item to be clickable as well:

```
android:focusable="false"
```